# VBA VLOOKUP formula to refer to a dynamic range in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

VBA VLOOKUP formula to refer to a dynamic range in another sheet

Hi,
I am trying to incorporate a VLOOKUP formula into a worksheet called "RESULTS" and reference a dynamic data range in another sheet called "DATA" via VBA - the formula I have works fine but it is not dynamic and I have not been unable to replicate it in the macro, as such, given my limited VBA skills, I have hit a bit of a brick wall so any adice and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the formula I want to replicate for use in the macro but, as mentioned, it is a fixed range and I need it to be dynamic:

=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IF({1,0},DATA!$C$5:$C$20000,DATA!$B$5:$B$20000),2,0),"")=0,"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IF({1,0},DATA!$C$5:$C$20000,DATA!$B$5:$B$20000),2,0),""))

Here is the VBA I have written - it is just the VLOOKUP formula that isn't working, the COUNTIFS formula is working fine.

```
Sub DATA_Report()
        
    'Add in formulae
    Dim DataLastRow As Long
    Dim ResultsLastRow As Long

    'Determine last row of DATA Scheme Information sheet
     With Sheets("DATA")
        DataLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    'Determine last row in col B for RESULTS sheet - Add in formula - MEMBER REFERENCE
    With Sheets("RESULTS")
    ResultsLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        'The following formula is not working
        .Range("G2:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],IF({1,0}," & "DATA!R5C3:R" & DataLastRow & ",DATA!R5C2:R" & DataLastRow & "),2,0)," & """"")=0," & """""," & "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],IF({1,0}," & "DATA!R5C3:R" & DataLastRow & ",DATA!R5C2:R" & DataLastRow & "),2,0),""""))"
        'The following COUNTIFS formula works fine
        .Range("H2:AA" & ResultsLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIFS(DATA!R5C2:R" & DataLastRow & "C2,RC7,DATA!R5C1:R" & DataLastRow & "C1,R1C)>0,""Yes"","""")"
    End With
End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance,
TE

Comment: When you say "isn't working" do you mean you are getting an error or you are not getting the result you want?  If error, what is the error?

Comment: I think you can do it directly with the "OFFSET" and the "COUNTA" functions in the following way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtxiQM416u0

Comment: Hi @darrell-h - thanks for your reply - to answer your question, the formula doesn't error, I don't get the result I want - I will amend my post to show the resulting formula that's generated via the VBA. Thanks again - TE

Comment: Hi @edoardo-berardo - thanks for providing the YouTube link - I'll bookmark that as it will be very useful in another project. However, in this instance, I really need VBA to accomplish this because the formula is just one apsect of a much larger macro that builds a report compiled from data contained in a number of other reports within the same workbook. My aim is to build the compiled report by running this macro and the VLOOKUP formula is my last remaining stumbling block. Thanks again and kindest regards, TE